# how to fix bootstrap column align

Tags: html, css

Hello I have website called: http://mtisambebi.ge/
There is module where I have boostrap cols, but one col is aligned left and I do not understand whay.

[this is screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1tY5c.jpg)

also module is called: ბოლო სიახლეები in main page.

Comment: Please read [Something on my web site doesn't work. Can I just paste a link to it?](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/125997/something-on-my-web-site-doesnt-work-can-i-just-paste-a-link-to-it). Questions that depend on external resources to be understood become useless when the external resource goes away or is fixed. Create a [MCVE] instead.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please add `<div class="clearfix"></div>` after every 3 column. where getting flot right

```
<div class="col-lg-4 col-md-4 col-sm-4 col-xs-12"></div>
<div class="col-lg-4 col-md-4 col-sm-4 col-xs-12"></div>
<div class="col-lg-4 col-md-4 col-sm-4 col-xs-12"></div>
<div class="clearfix"></div>
<div class="col-lg-4 col-md-4 col-sm-4 col-xs-12"></div>
<div class="col-lg-4 col-md-4 col-sm-4 col-xs-12"></div>
<div class="col-lg-4 col-md-4 col-sm-4 col-xs-12"></div>
```

Comment: you can select my answer and no need to any reputation

Comment: selected, Thank you